# php stop script process that is already running

Tags: php, execution

I have a php program that does extensive curl requests to scrape web pages. It could be up to a million requests. I need to completely stop the script from running. Even though I stopped it in my browser, it is still processing requests. How can I stop it permanently?

Comment: Should always have a kill switch for these sort of situations >.< Restart (web) server?

Comment: I get the general idea now that what I did is bad practice :| Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just killing the request, you will need to stop apache to stop it for now.  In the future redesign it so that the process looks for a kill switch (like the presence of a file) and stops processing if it finds it.  Sounds like you are jamming a long running process into a php script, why not run it as a normal system process directly?

Comment: So this could be as simple as checking for a `maintenance.flag` for instance?

Comment: Sure, pretty much anything.  A file in /tmp for example.

Comment: Great, everything is a learning process I guess. I will plan for this in the future for every bigger project.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are running the typical lamp stack, SSH into your machine, if necessary, and restart Apache.

If you are really going to perform long running tasks with PHP, I must suggest you consider using cron to run them or implement a task queue of some sort.  It's generally a really bad idea to have these sort of things fired from a browser request.

Answer (score 2):

Restart Apache. If you're using XAMP, stop and start it from the control panel.

If not, on Windows, go to task manager and end the `apache.exe` process. Then start it again.